# VB MS Access 97 Having count (distinct ) error

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT patient.id
     , patient.name
FROM patient,patientdx
WHERE patient.id = patientdx.id
      AND disease IN ('HIV', 'DM')
GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT disease) = 2;
```

The problem is `COUNT(DISTINCT )` , not supported by 97 version. Is there alternative query to get the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should learn to use proper `join` syntax.  However, you can do what you want without aggregation by using `IN`:

```
SELECT patient.*
FROM patient
WHERE patient.id IN (SELECT id FROM patientdx WHERE disease = 'HIV') AND
      patient.id IN (SELECT id FROM patientdx WHERE disease = 'DM');
```

Although there are ways to make the aggregation query work, this provides an alternative to the aggregation query.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may work for you.

```
...
HAVING
    MAX(disease) = 'HIV' AND MIN(disease) = 'DM'
AND MAX(IIF(disease > 'DM' AND disease < 'HIV', 1, 0)) = 0
```

To translate: Biggest `disease` alphabetically is HIV and the lowest is DM. The other expression makes sure nothing falls between them.

EDIT: I hadn't noticed you were already limiting `disease` in the `WHERE` clause to the two of interest. So I can see that your purpose in using `HAVING` is to make sure that patient has both of those diagnoses. This makes the last condition redundant in your case but possibly a handy trick in the future. To restate, I think this simpler conditional is sufficient for you.

```
HAVING MAX(disease) = 'HIV' AND MIN(disease) = 'DM'
```

You can certainly try out the first one and let us/me know if Access 97 handles it ok.